# using Rotativa to convert html to PDF

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, pdf-generation, html-to-pdf, rotativa

I'm using Rotativa to convert Html to Pdf. This is the function in my controller Fax

```
    public ActionResult ExportPDF()
    {
        return new PartialViewAsPdf("SearchForm")
        {
            FileName = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Invoice.pdf")
        };
    }
```

It converts SearchForm as empty, not how I want it - full with it's fields and the result of the search after it, like this picture:

[SearchForm view after clicked in search button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7XKT.png)